# curl on macos problem with unicode characters

Tags: bash, macos, curl, unicode

I have script that runs on MacOS
it uses curl to fetch a json containing files on a sharepoint site.

All works fine but the response from curl when running in bash or sh has the unicode characters written out in \uxxxx format.

```
for example ö is \u00f6
"Name":"\u00f6vning.dotx"
```

but when running with zsh it encodes correctly.

Any idea why and can you get it working using bash or sh?

```
#!/bin/sh
url="https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Testfiles"
folder="TestDocuments"

files=$(curl -s $url"/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/"$folder"')/Files" -H "Accept: application/json")
echo $files
```

when running curl -v

```
GET /sites/Testfiles/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('Documents/TestDocuments')/Files HTTP/1.1
> Host: company.sharepoint.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: application/json
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: application/json;odata=minimalmetadata;streaming=true;charset=utf-8
```

here's the complete json response

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Testfiles/_api/$metadata#SP.ApiData.Files12",
    "value": [
        {
            "odata.type": "SP.File",
            "odata.id": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Testfiles/_api/Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/Testfiles/Documents/TestDocs/\u00f6vning.dotx')",
            "odata.editLink": "Web/GetFileByServerRelativePath(decodedurl='/sites/Testfiles/Documents/TestDocs/%C3%B6vning.dotx')",
            "CheckInComment": "",
            "CheckOutType": 2,
            "ContentTag": "{39C1CD78-3674-49F4-9982-214B33FC03BE},2,5",
            "CustomizedPageStatus": 0,
            "ETag": "\"{39C1CD78-3674-49F4-9982-214B33FC03BE},2\"",
            "Exists": true,
            "IrmEnabled": false,
            "Length": "48725",
            "Level": 1,
            "LinkingUri": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Testfiles/Documents/TestDocs/\u00f6vning.dotx?d=w11c1cd78361119f49982214b33fd43be",
            "LinkingUrl": "https://company.sharepoint.com/sites/Testfiles/Documents/TestDocs/\u00f6vning.dotx?d=w11c1cd78361119f49982214b33fd43be",
            "MajorVersion": 1,
            "MinorVersion": 0,
            "Name": "\u00f6vning.dotx",
            "ServerRelativeUrl": "/sites/Testfiles/Documents/TestDocs/\u00f6vning.dotx",
            "TimeCreated": "2021-10-14T13:32:16Z",
            "TimeLastModified": "2021-10-14T13:32:16Z",
            "Title": "",
            "UIVersion": 512,
            "UIVersionLabel": "1.0",
            "UniqueId": "39c1cd78-3674-49f4-9982-214b33fc03be"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I don't see `ö` or any non-ascii characters in your example.

Comment: This is how `ö` is represented in JSON.

Comment: added how the json response from curl looks like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `bash`, you need to use the `-e` option to have `echo` expand the `\u` escapes to UTF-8 sequences that your terminal can display.

```
$ x='"\u00f6vning.dotx"'
$ echo "$x"
"\u00f6vning.dotx"
$ echo -e "$x"
"övning.dotx"
```

First, we have a "coincidence" that JSON, `bash` and `zsh` use the same syntax (`\u....`) for representing arbitrary Unicode code points in plain ASCII. This is *not* true for POSIX-compliant shells in general, so I don't think you can *expect* this to work when running `sh`, regardless of which shell is actually used. (In practice, it does not work with `bash` 3.2, but does work with later versions of `bash`.)

`zsh`'s implementation of `echo` is XSI-compliant, in that it expands various character sequences by default. (`\u` itself is not defined by XSI, but `zsh` includes them in the list of sequences expanded by `echo`.) (POSIX compliance for `echo` is fairly loose, stating only that arguments containing backslashes can be handled in an implementation-specific manner.)

`bash`'s implemeantion of `echo` is *not* XSI-compliant by default. `-e` enables the expansion of backslash sequences, as would setting the `xpg_echo` shell option.

```
$ shopt -s xpg_echo
$ echo "$x"
"övning.dotx"
```

Comment: Any comments for clarifying exactly how POSIX compliance affects the interpretation of `\u` are welcome. I've rewritten this several times in an attempt to be accurate.

Comment: POSIX allows leeway for `\u...` escape sequences by simply stating that the results are implementation defined when any operand to `echo` contains a backslash character, so it shouldn't affect their interpretation at all.

Comment: Good point. XSI-conformant systems are required to expand `\a` et al., but nothing seems to prohibit expanding other sequences as well.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, have to stick to zsh i guess

Comment: No, you should treat `curl`'s output for what it is: JSON. Pipe the output through `jq '.Name'`, for example, and use any shell you like to call `jq`.

Answer (score 1):

To have same command working on both bash and zsh :

```
printf "%b\n" "\u00f6vning.dotx"
```